# why does vscode's intellisense keeps performing code completion whenever I try to type the rest operator into arrow function as a parameter?

Tags: rest, visual-studio-code, arrow-functions, code-hinting

Whenever I try to type 3 periods in a roll into an arrow function as the parameter, VSCode always performs code completion with the function name, as follow:

[image]

This, however, does not happen with a regular function declaration.

```
function question(...answers) {
  return answers;
}
```

Does anyone know how to remedy this strange behavior? I don't recall this ever happening in prior versions of VSCode.

PS: VSCode Version: 1.59.0

Comment: This is a bug. Did you file a bug for this? EDIT: here it is: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130096

Comment: Thanks "BrDaHa" for the link :) I truly hope the next update of VSCode will remove this bug. But for those who shares the same predicament as I do, the current solution is to add the following to settings.json: "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false Here is the link: github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130266

Answer (score 0):

That's because in the code you have in that image, you are still not declaring an arrow function. Just writing a value inside some parentheses.

If you instead write the arrow expression first you should have no problem:

```js
const question = () => {};
```

Still, did you change some setting related to autocompletion?

Comment: Thanks Manuel for the reply. I've tried declaring the arrow function as well as declaring the whole function and the behavior still remains. I don't recall changing any setting related to autocompletion at all but I do welcome any suggestions regarding the setting that might prevent this predicament.